# Azure CLI won't login on MacOS

Tags: macos, azure, command-line-interface

I am trying to login into the Azure CLI but when I run az login I get these error messages:

```
Roberts-Mac-Pro:~ robertcordingly$ az login
Port '8400' is taken with error '[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'. Trying with the next one
Port '8401' is taken with error '[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'. Trying with the next one
Port '8402' is taken with error '[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'. Trying with the next one
Port '8403' is taken with error '[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'. Trying with the next one
Port '8404' is taken with error '[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'. Trying with the next one
Port '8405' is taken with error '[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'. Trying with the next one
Error: can't reserve a port for authentication reply url
Login failed
```

I cut out most of the lines as it appears that it simply loops through a bunch of ports and gets Error number 8 every time.

If you have any idea why this is happening, I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you install azure cli? use below [brew formula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-macos?view=azure-cli-latest)

```
 brew update && brew install azure-cli
```

Comment: That is exactly what I used to install it. Tried once again and got the same results: https://imgur.com/Tb6vawl

Edit: Reinstalling with brew results in the same thing. A big loop through ports and ultimately ending with "Error: can't reserve a port for authentication reply url"

Comment: Hey are you using any VPN check below issue 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7227

Comment: I do not use a VPN but I was able to login using az login --use-device-code Thanks for sharing this link!

Comment: It's my pleasure to help

Answer (score 2):

On a mac add the following line to you hosts.

> sudo vi /etc/hosts
>
> 0.0.0.0     localhost

This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

From your terminal:

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

then:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Comment: I had changed localhost to something for testing. I changed to your solution and I can login now. However I dont know what localhost and the 127.0.0.1 means for azure in general